# Why is the amount in a mole equal to the Avogadro's number?

Tags: mole

This question just popped in my head as I was working with electric force problems involving atoms. Why is the amount in a mole equal to the Avogadro's number? Do atoms/molecules/etc. tend to group in this exact amount? Why do we use this number as a unit of measurement?

Comment: It's simply defined that way.

Comment: If this is an arbitrary, though mutually agreed upon, number, how did Avogadro come up with the number? Are there any benefits to using his number as opposed to a randomly large number?

Comment: related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35563/what-advantages-does-the-mole-have-over-counting-large-numbers-using-si-prefixes?rq=1, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/11169/why-is-the-definition-of-the-mole-as-it-is?rq=1, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5321/why-is-the-mole-a-unit-of-measurement?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avogadro articulated the concept that is Avogadro's number, but didn't pick the number. From Wikipedia:

> Avogadro's law states that, "equal volumes of all gases, at the same temperature and pressure, have the same number of molecules".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro%27s_law

The Number is a logical extension of this law: So what is that number in relation to the volume and what is the mass of that amount of material?  By agreement, a mole is defined as the mass, in grams, equivalent to the atomic weight of a substance. This was laid out before Avogadro's Number was actually determined.  Then it was simply a matter of measuring the mass of a single atom to determine how many atoms were required to have a Mole of a material.  Over time, Avogadro's Number has been refined to more and more accuracy.