How can atomic weight be the same in amu and grams?
Working on:

Richard Post, Chad Snyder, Clifford C. Houk. (2020). Chemistry: Concepts and Problems, A Self-Teaching Guide, 3rd Edition (p. 56)

The authors explain:

Atomic weights are based on the carbon-12 scale. That is, $\ce{^{12}_{6}C}$, the most abundant isotope of carbon, is used as the standard for measuring atomic weights. By international agreement, one atom of the $\ce{^{12}_{6}C}$ isotope is assigned an atomic weight of exactly 12 atomic mass units (amu).


The atomic weight of the $\ce{^{12}_{6}C}$ isotope is exactly 12 amu.

Frame 40 says:

(40) The average atomic weight of neon ($\ce{Ne}$) is 20.180 according to the periodic table (rounded off to the nearest thousandth).


(a) The average weight of one neon ($\ce{Ne}$) atom is how many amu? 20.180


(b) The average weight of 6.022×1023 neon atoms is how many grams? 20.180

In both cases, the solution provided by the book is 20.180. How is it possible for the average weight to be exactly the same when using two different units (amu and grams)? Could this be a mistake in the book?

Though I don't see why you'd think it's atomic mass in grams - it's molar mass.

Note that amu is the obsolete and ambiguous unit that somehow kicks around and will not leave easily. // The mass of carbon-12 atom is exactly 12 Da (Dalton) while the mass of oxygen-16 atoms  was exactly 16 amu (phys) and the mean mass of 1 atom of natural oxygen  was exactly 16 amu(chem). The unit amu was abandoned (not redefined, to prevent future confusions)  and replaced by Dalton (Da).

amu is used in mass of one single atom
but
gram is used in mass of one mole number of atoms(1 mole atom = 6.022 x 10^23 atoms!)

Hi guys, the linked post doesn't directly answer my question. I wondered about the provided answers in the book. Seemed surprising to me that two different units to express weight had the same exact number. For me, it's like saying: "The length of this bridge is 100 kilometres, and 100 cm". That's why I wanted to ask.

Well, one cubic cm of water weighs 1g and one cubic meter weighs one tonne - how are both values one?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35650/why-is-the-amount-in-a-mole-equal-to-the-avogadros-number

That's a good point, @Mithoron. Thank you
